# An app ID with Identifier 'com.Company.ProductName' is not avalible, please enter a different string

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

Trying to test my unity app in xcode and when I click run it says:

> An app ID with Identifier 'com.Company.ProductName' is not avalible, please enter a different string

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: You can change the Bundle Identifier in Unity .

Comment: Ok, not sure what I should change it to though, does it matter? And do I still need to include the com. part

Comment: It is very important to change to a valid Bundle Identifier, instead of the default one. You cannot use the default value to run an App. Learn what is Bundle Identifier before you proceed anything else.

Answer (score 5):

App ID must be globally unique. That is why reverse DNS naming convention is suggested. Please ensure your `Bundle Identifier` is unique.

Comment: Also, make sure that your ID is not something like `com.unity3d.MyAppIsCool`. I was stuck because I thought the name `unity3d` was unique but it's not.

Answer (score 2):

Before you build your app, in unity go into -

Build Settings > Player Settings > Bundle Identifier

Change this to com.Company.ProductName format. 
You can change your company and product name in the player settings.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem when i upgraded my Xcode to 7.3 and it showed me the same error in every project. The simplest solution that i found was to just the remove the apple account from Xcode and add it again.

To remove just go to Xcode > Preferences > Select the account and click on - sign.

[image]

If in case this still doesn't work . Then perform a next step of downing your provisioning profile again and run it.

Hope this helps. All the best

Answer (score 0):

None of the typical solutions for this problem worked for me.  I then found this from Apple:

> Xcode unable to create distribution builds for App Store submissions or Enterprise apps.
>   This issue occurs when the expired WWDR Intermediate certificate is present in both the System keychain and Login keychain within the Keychain Access application. To resolve the issue, first download and install the renewed certificate. Next, in the Keychain Access application, select the System keychain. Select 'Show Expired Certificates' in the View menu and then delete the expired version of the Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority Intermediate certificate. Your certificates should now appear as valid in Keychain Access and be available to Xcode.

Replacing the WWDR Intermediate certificate per Apple's directions worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that you have done the right thing and that the App ID is correct.

The solution is as follows:
Quit Xcode, just to be sure.
Remove all the existing provision profiles on your mac, you can find them in:
/YourHomeDirectory/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/
This way, you have a clean sheet to begin.

In Member Center, remove the related profiles in the Distribution section of your iOS Certificate (the profiles you used to Archive your app with). Than recreate them one by one and when creating, make sure to select the right Distribution and the right App ID.
After that, download those new profiles to your mac. Than double click on those profiles so Xcode automatically adds them to the folder:
/YourHomeDirectory/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/
You can check that the profiles are added there (but the filenames are changed to a hashed kind of character).

Start Xcode and try to Archive your app again, if you followed the steps well, distributing should now work. Good luck!